# configure prod and dev url in ionic1

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

Is there anyway I can configure separate URLs for production and Dev environment. I want to have 2 different environment variable which can be used on demand basis while building app.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://jbavari.github.io/blog/2014/08/23/managing-environment-variables-for-your-ionic-application/) you can preprocess a file – say ‘AppSettings.js’ that will expose some variables for the rest of your application to use. This could contain those pesky variables that you will need to change frequently.

Hope I help!